# Why is font not listed by fc-list after running fc-cache on font

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

Im working on a linux blackbox system, uname -a gives

```
 Linux 0247 3.3.4-ROMROOT-NT1 #1 Fri Nov 17 14:46:03 JST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

There is only one font on the system

```
 /usr/lib/fonts/ipag.ttf
```

but `fc-list` return nothing

So I try to install it properly

```
[root@0247]# sudo fc-cache -rv /usr/lib/fonts
/usr/lib/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/root/.cache/fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
/root/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

font seems to be installed, but still `fc-list` returns nothing, why is that ?